# SQL Server NULL Values with an Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is not doing what I want, I am not sure how to solve this:

```
DECLARE @RoomMap TABLE
    (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    SourceRoom int,--> SourceRoomID
    SourceSiteID int,
    TargetRoom int, -->DemoRoomID
    TargetSiteID int
    )

INSERT INTO @RoomMap
(SourceRoom, SourceSiteID)
SELECT tblControls_Rooms.ID, @origSiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @OrigSiteID

INSERT INTO @RoomMap
(TargetRoom, TargetSiteID)
SELECT tblControls_Rooms.ID, @NewSiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @newSiteID

INSERT INTO DemoRoomMap 
(DemoRoomID, SourceRoomID)
SELECT TargetRoom, SourceRoom
FROM @RoomMap
```

THIS is the DemoRoomMap table when I run it:

```
TargetRoom  SourceRoom
    332 2
    333 3
    334 4
    335 5
    336 6
    337 9
    338 10
```

The result when I run the above query:

```
TargetRoom  SourceRoom
NULL    1942
NULL    1943
NULL    1944
NULL    1945
NULL    1946
2025    NULL
2026    NULL
2027    NULL
2028    NULL
```

As you can see, there are `NULL` values which I really do not want to insert! How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Saying that the query is "not doing what you want" is not much of an information. Please explain what do you want query to do, provide some sample data and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of them by inserting a value into them. See, this statement doesn't insert a value into `TargetRoom`:

```
INSERT INTO @RoomMap
(SourceRoom, SourceSiteID)
SELECT tblControls_Rooms.ID, @origSiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @OrigSiteID
```

Further, the subsequent statement doesn't insert values into `SourceRoom`:

```
INSERT INTO @RoomMap
(TargetRoom, TargetSiteID)
SELECT tblControls_Rooms.ID, @NewSiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @newSiteID
```

So, when you're done, you get a set of rows without `TargetRoom` and a set of rows without `SourceRoom`.

Comment: I am still not sure how to do it.

Comment: @HotlansyHttlandy, I can understand that. But from my perspective I answered the question at hand. I don't really know what you want because that's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RoomMap TABLE
(ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
SourceRoom int,--> SourceRoomID
SourceSiteID int,
TargetRoom int, -->DemoRoomID
TargetSiteID int
)

INSERT INTO @RoomMap
(SourceRoom, SourceSiteID, TargetRoom TargetSiteID )
SELECT S.ID, @origSiteID, T.ID, @NewSiteID
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID FROM tblControls_Rooms WHERE SiteID = @OrigSiteID
) S
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT ID FROM tblControls_Rooms WHERE SiteID = @NewSiteID
) T
```

Comment: I want to the TargetRoom and SourceRoom into DemoRoomMap but I want them distinct! one source room, one targer room in the query above I am getting the following:1942 2025
1943 2025
1944 2025
1945 2025
1946 2025